# Open/Close Workbook in Userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

In a Userform I want to open another workbook (than the active one)
Part of my code:

```vb
Private Sub cmbKontoPos1_Change()

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=filename1
    'Here should of course be some code, but it is not now 
    Workbooks(filename1).Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Open-command works.

But the Close-command gives error:

```
 Error no '9'
 Index out of bounds
```

(I get the error-message in Swedish, hope I translate correct)

What is it I do not understand?

Comment: Does `filename1` get changed at any point? Do a `debug.print` on it.

Comment: It sounds like another part of your code is attempting to access beyond the length of the file. Without more about your code between the open and close it would be hard to tell what is happening.

Comment: When closing the workbook, you need to refer to it by name without incuding its path.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix is to have a global Workbook Variable so you can assign it on Open and use it on other UserForm Events, the example below has two Buttons and one opens while the other one closes the Workbook. Tested and working.

You can see the `Dim secondWorkbook` outside the UserForm buttons this is to make it global. On the first button I assign the Opened workbook to that Variable and i can close it later.

```
Dim secondWorkbook As Workbook
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'Open WB
    Dim filename1 As String
    filename1 = "F:\WorkbookPath\WBName.xlsx"
    Set secondWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(filename1)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    'Close WB
    secondWorkbook.Close False
End Sub
```

You can also use this variable to make changes to the workbook like: `secondWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Test"` as long as it is still open of course.